# How can I get the cached credentials in application startup on XDK platform?

Tags: caching, intel-xdk, login-script

I have stored the login detials into a cache file by using these lines in the login process.

```
intel.xdk.cache.setCookie("userid",username,50);
intel.xdk.cache.setCookie("password",password,50);
```

I want the app to remember credentials so I thought somehow I have to get them while in init-app.js file  and forward to content page .

Which method should I use to forward to specific page in js by passing the index.html page?
And is this the appropriate way to do cache authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use `localStorage.setItem("password", password);` and retrieve it using `localStorage.getItem("password");`

Don't store passwords in localstorage. What i do,

1. User authenticates using username and password from app
2. Server authenticates the request and sends a token (Json Web Token) which is then stored in localStorage
3. The app will then query the User's profile using the token